# Compile-time usage introspection

Tags: c++

I have been trying to come up with a solution to this problem for a while and so far, everyone told me it was impossible around me so I though I'd give SO a try.

Here is the problem : people using environment variables and not properly either testing for the result or silently using hard-coded alternative.

What I wanted to do was come up with a small library that people would use instead of getenv that could, at initialization time, inform the user of the env. variables the program might be using. This would only imply doing a replace of getenv for this call and placing a single function call at the initialization of the executable or library (I would not deal with dynamic env. variable name making such as using a string constructed).

Here is a quick example I was able to make (http://ideone.com/Wi1JBq)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

static vector<string> test;

template <char const *str>
struct EnvVar
{
    EnvVar()
    {
        test.push_back(string(str));
    }
    const char* GetEnvVarName() const
    {
        return str;
    }
};

static void checkVars()
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < test.size(); i++)
        cout << "Predefined : " << test[i] << endl;
}

#define GENERATE_ENV_VAR(Name) char _##Name[] = #Name; static EnvVar<_ ## Name> Name;

// ----- What is actually in the user file -----

GENERATE_ENV_VAR(FirstEnvVar)
GENERATE_ENV_VAR(SecondEnvVar)
GENERATE_ENV_VAR(ThirdEnvVar)

int main()
{
    checkVars();
    cout << "Usage : " << FirstEnvVar.GetEnvVarName() << endl;
    cout << "Usage : " << SecondEnvVar.GetEnvVarName() << endl;
    cout << "Usage : " << ThirdEnvVar.GetEnvVarName() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This outputs

```
Predefined : FirstEnvVar
Predefined : SecondEnvVar
Predefined : ThirdEnvVar
Usage : FirstEnvVar
Usage : SecondEnvVar
Usage : ThirdEnvVar
```

It's quite obvious why it does so, the macro being used at the global level, this is initialized before the main is entered, that is why the first function calls know about them. What I want to do is not have those, so basically, have this :

```
int main()
{
    checkVars();
    cout << "Usage : " << FirstEnvVar.GetEnvVarName() << endl;
    cout << "Usage : " << SecondEnvVar.GetEnvVarName() << endl;
    cout << "Usage : " << ThirdEnvVar.GetEnvVarName() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and get the same output. I'm sure it would involve a lot of template/macro hacking but it would be great. I would prefer not just having a script that parses the code and generate code but I know this could be a solution. I want pure C++ if possible, boost can be fine.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why does it need to be a template class?  You should just be able to pass `#NAME` into a constructor that accepts `const char *`.  The run time will call constructors for all file-scope variable instances before reaching your code in `main`.

```
class EnvVar
{ 
  private:
    const char *const str;

  public:
    static vector<string> env_vars;

    EnvVar(const char *str_) : str(str_)
    {
        env_vars.push_back(string(str_));  // this vector seems redundant...
    }
    const char* GetEnvVarName() const
    {
        return str;
    }
};

#define GENERATE_ENV_VAR(Name)  EnvVar Name##_( #Name );

GENERATE_ENV_VAR(FirstEnvVar)
GENERATE_ENV_VAR(SecondEnvVar)
GENERATE_ENV_VAR(ThirdEnvVar)
```

You'll also notice that I moved your underscore to the end of the variable name, as leading underscores followed by uppercase letters are reserved to the compiler.

Also, the `vector<string>` seems redundant.  It may actually make more sense to have a central registry of `EnvVar` pointers that the class registers itself with, like this:

```
class EnvVar
{ 
  private:
    const char *const str;

  public:
    static vector<class EnvVar *> registry;

    EnvVar(const char *str_) : str(str_)
    {
        registry.push_back(this);  // register ourselves
    }
    const char* GetEnvVarName() const
    {
        return str;
    }
};
```

Then you can always walk through the complete registry of environment variables by iterating over `EnvVars::registry`.

Comment: but to fill the static vector, you need to go over the code. The point is that the code has not been over the code at that point yet. I want the GENERATE_ENV_VAR to be gone from the local scope. The point of it being a template class was me doing a test, because it generates code.

Comment: I see, you want to eliminate those macros at the global level.  I missed that paragraph in the middle.  Yeah, I don't see a way of, at compile time, generating this list.  You might be able to do something really gross with `static` variables.  Let me try something and get back to you.

Comment: Never mind... that won't work either because `static` vars aren't  initialized until the block gets reached.

Comment: Quite a complex problem huh? Really been bugging my mind for a while.

Comment: Yeah, you might be better off with a post-processing script that runs `nm` on all the objects, looks for symbols with a particular name pattern, and then builds a table in a separate .cpp that gets compiled in at the end.  (ie. solve it in the build process if you can.)